# Which WoW class/spec has the best mobility for questing and solo'ing low level dungeons

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I want to raise a character to do quests and running low level dungeons for achievements. With lvl90 stats, DPS and survival are generally not issues, hence mobility has paramount importance for efficiency.

Based on my observation, some possible candidates are

- WW Monk, with Roll and Flying Serpent Kick.
- Feral druid, in Cat Form with Dash and Stampede Roar.
- Warlock, with Burning Rush.
- Rogue. I've generally seen them moving fast but haven't figured out what spell it is.

Some other possibilities, unlikely the fastest but I am not sure

- Priest, with Angelic Feather.
- Shaman, in Ghost Wolf form.

Since I haven't tried all of these classes myself, I'd like to know: *in reality*, which class/spec has the best mobility in the context mentioned earlier?

Comment: Update: I've been experimenting Warlock with Burning Rush. The speed is okay (+50%), but it really doesn't sustain long enough to cover the distance from one boss to the next, even without any adds in between. The larger the instance is, the less useful Burning Rush can be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rogues are the quickest.  With enough haste you can have a 100% uptime on 'Burst of Speed' which is a 70% movement speed. Since it doesn't break stealth anymore, you can use it with nightstalker. Not to mention the passive 15% movement speed rogues already get + sprint.

To add onto that, if you want more energy regen to fan of knives while running, go subtlety.

1) Use marked for death on an enemy (gives 5 cp)

2) Use slice and dice (grants 4 energy/sec while up for subtletly)

3) Kill the monster you marked to get mark for death back off cooldown.

4) Rinse and repeat when slice and dice is about to fall off

Comment: Should I pick Nightstalker or Shadow Focus for lv15 talent, or does it matter?

Comment: I definitely recommend Nightstalker.  I tested it on my rogue just now and my movement speed goes from 170% -> 204% with the talent in stealth.  My energy regens fast enough that I can reapply Burst of Speed when it still has 2 seconds left so you should be fine with energy.  That being said, you should be in stealth the whole time you're roaming

Comment: I haven't played wow in like 10 years so I wonder whatever happened to Hunter class - they used to have passive speed auras and whatnot that gave them high average speed even if in bursts other classes could be faster

Answer (score 1):

Warriors are a really great choice for rushing through old instances and Raids. While they do not have the highest movementspeed they still have a high mobility (Charge, Jump etc) and what makes them really great is their ability to survive **everything**.

If you chose the Health regen below 35% HP you can literally pull whole dungeons and clear everything at once with Bladestorm or other AOE abilities.

The "Unkillable-Factor" Makes you faster since other classes often have to stop and heal or they don't have any heal at all which forces them to stay and reg or pull slowly.

When it comes to mobility you should always use your heroic leap, charge and intervene (banners usually) on cooldown while you can also pull groups with your ranged abilites.

Answer (score 1):

Havoc Demon Hunters can outrun trash and murder all of it in 1 shot with their dash. High mastery, means even faster speed. Sure not 100% sprint, but your speed is faster than a feral druid or shaman in ghost wolf.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a druid. They're highly adaptive and mobile (with `Dash`, `Stampeding Roar` and `Feline Swiftness` as standard, and `Enchant Boots: Pandaren's Step` for a small running speed and a 140-pt mastery boost).

They can self-heal (`Cenarion Ward`, `Ysera's Gift`), with plenty of HoTs at your disposal. Balance are great for boosting the healing aspect whilst DPSing, Feral are great for quick dispatch of enemies at the cost of the healing boost.
Guardians are tanks - which also come with some self-healing abilities.

If you chose Horde, then an Undead Druid (if Blizzard ever decide to add it (unlikely)) would be able to use `Cannibalise`.