# Which is the fastest class in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

After experimenting a bit with the Death Knight and the Druid, I've been wondering which of the classes in the game has the potential to be the fastest at level 90. I'm looking for the following qualifyers:

- All class features and spells that create a faster form for the character (the Druid's forms, the Shaman's Spirit Wolf and so on)
- Abilities that give a flat increase to speed: via spells, glyphs and talents. (Feline Swiftness, Death's Advance and others)
- Equipable or usable items that give a bonus to speed at level 90, are not bound to location and has a duration of AT LEAST as long as the cooldown.
- Mounts that can be used in any locations you are allowed to use mounts (this will likely boil down to a flying mount with Master Riding, but I'm asking just in case).

And are there maybe other things that I have missed that can make you go faster?

Comment: When I played wow there were some items which increase the mount speed. "Enchants" to boots from a blacksmith (spikes) and some trinkets like a carrot :)

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168864/which-wow-class-spec-has-the-best-mobility-for-questing-and-soloing-low-level-d

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First I'll go through speeds without mounts (assuming you're inside - which excludes druids travel form):

**Fastest passive on Foot**

**Hunter** - they have access to Aspect of the Cheetah and Glyph of Pathfinding, which increases movement speed by 38%.

**Fastest speed on foot when using activated abilities**

**Rogue** - Stealthed rogue with the bonus is 131% (which is slower than the hunter), but you can use Burst of Speed infinitely which will bring it up to 204%.. in addition they can occasionally use sprint which is a temporary speed boost that totals at 220%.

Runner up - **Paladin** - with the correct talent and always having 3+ holy power, they can run fast as well.

---

Now let's talk about mount speed.

**Death Knights** and **Paladins** are tied when on mounts. I'll talk about flying mounts for the sake of numbers.

Death Knights have access to Pale Horse, and Paladins have access to Crusader.. if you have those with the fastest possible flying mount skill and the fastest type of mount (310%), and have the guild perk which increases mount speed, you can get up to a total of 392%.

---

As for stacking movement effects.. not many effects stack with each other as of Cataclysm/MoP. Some examples:

**Carrot on a Stick** will indeed increase your movement speed, but it does not stack with effects such as Crusader. Therefore, once you get crusader, the movement speed bonus from Carrot on a Stick becomes useless.

**Mithril Spurs** also becomes obsolete when you get the guild perk "Mount Up". The same goes for Riding Crop and the Riding Skill enchant.

---

In conclusion, the fastest mounted classes are **Paladins** and **Death Knights**, while the fastest class on foot is the **Rogue**.

Comment: I feel like this is incorrect for on-foot speed... When me and my raid mates would rush back to a boss, the class that made it back first would be the Druids followed by the Engineering Mages, then the Engineering Rogues. Druid's run speed is very fast in cat form and Mage mobility (Blazing Speed and Glyphed Blink) coupled with Engineering items made them nearly as fast.

Comment: I excluded druids travel form as noted in my answer.. in some raids you can use travel form. Mages may have been fast in the past, especially with the improved invisibility.. but now they are among the slowest classes in the game, as all they have is blink (x2 if glyphed), and blazing speed which is only a 1.5 second boost. The reason why engineering is especially fast with mages is because you can use blazing speed then jump and parachute.. so technically speaking you are correct, but then again that's not "on foot" - is it?

Comment: It's also important to note that in raids, hunters and rogues likely don't have the glyphs/talents/spec required in order to run the fastest they can.. and people with parachutes in raids are likely trying to race and show off how fast they can go with their engineering. While many other classes are probably running into walls while getting a drink, getting there casually, etc.

Comment: Fastest passive on foot would be a Feral Druid: Constant 155% with Cat Form in/out of stealth/combat. (And with Travel Form constant 174% but only outside.)

Comment: Engineering also includes the Rocket Boosts. Mage's cooldowns allow them to use Blink, Blazing Speed, and Rocket Boosts nearly in succession. Over longer distances, this loses it's effectiveness as the cooldown of the Rocket Boosts is longer. However, if there are any downward ramps on the way, Mages can use Slow Fall at the end of Blazing Speed as well as the Engineering Goblin Glider to give themselves variable amounts of increased speed (which can help use up the time between cooldowns). From my observations, Mages have always been exceptionally fast, not at all among the slowest.

Comment: The Death Knight thing is inaccurate: I can get 492% speed while flying at 310% with On A Pale Horse and Death's Advance, without any other item or guild bonus.

Comment: @Koviko Really no idea what you're talking about. You actually mention Blazing Speed?! What the heck, man! This spell lasts 1.5 sec! This isn't something for speed or PvE, this is an anti-snare PvP skill. And blink is on a 15 sec cooldown. Rocket Boosts have nothing to do with Mages. Mages ARE among the slowest classes in the game in terms of movement speed and its buffs. This is a fact. So really, this isn't something any sane person should be arguing against. Whatever you observed in your raid might've been 'cause no combat rogues had Burst of Speed, but NO class can outrun BoS for long.

Comment: @Rok Perhaps things have changed since 2014, but my comment was from personal experience of racing after wipes against Druids and Rogues and winning depending on how well the terrain worked with Slow Fall, as it preserved your speed prior to use.

Comment: Carrot on a Stick and Mithril Spurs do not work for players above level 70.

Answer (score 1):

All characters have the same base speed, so the following is the fastest (I believe)

Up to level 70 it would be Epic Mount (100%) + Carrot on a Stick (3%) + Riding Skill Enchant (2%) + Mithril Spurs (4%) giving a total of 218% of the base speed

Rogues with Nightstalker and spamming Burst of Speed will give you 204% speed

Shaman and Druid's travel forms will, when combined with the PVP-Rare set gives a 161% increase sustained.

Get those people to then carry Runeblade of Baron Rivendare (+8%) and a boot speed enchantment (8%) and I think that's your max.  Most movement speed boosts don't stack.

You could have burst speed improvements, but over a long period of time the sustained speed will beat them.

Answer (score 0):

Havoc Demon Hunters. I have 35%+ movement speed due to mastery(do not use mastery for anything other than this), not to mention the double dash and backflip. With enough mastery stacked, they can potentially be the fastest by merely running.

Comment: What is the limit to the mastery you can stack before it doesn't do increase speed?